# Identify location of painting

Tags: germany, identify-this, where-on-earth, berlin

I am trying to identify the location of a 1939 painting by Kurt Leyde. He painted this near the end of his life (d. 1941) and was born and died in Berlin. Apart from that, I don’t have much history on the piece. Since it was around the beginning of World War II, I was thinking it could be a pre-war depiction of the town. I was hoping someone might be able to recognize the area.

[image: Kurt Leyde (1881-1941) painting from 1939]

Comment: *...a pre-war depiction of [Berlin]*. It doesn't look like an urban location at all.

Comment: How do you know it is a Kurt Leyde painting?  Leyde was a reasonably famous painter, yet a google reverse image of this image returns nothing.  But a reverse image search of other works known to be his does show them up.

Comment: Nor does google turn it up on a simple image search for 'Kurt Leyde'.

Comment: @PeterM I was able to confirm his signature (lower left) with some of his other works. The “L” was pretty distinctive.

Comment: And browsing his painting sold at auction shows nothing else with this sort of subject

Comment: @RickKarlson And of course no one ever in the history of art ever forged a signature of a famous painter /s   But I am suspicious that this image isn't found elsewhere online.

Comment: When you crop and enhance the signature and date the first letter isn't much like an L, but it does look like the signature on other paintings.

Comment: Even if it’s not Leyde, I’m not looking to sell it. I was just curious where this was (if possible).

Comment: It may not even be a real scene.

Comment: That’s very possible, that was why I asked originally in the event it was a real scene.

Comment: @RickKarlson The only way you are likely going to know is by knowing the provenance of this painting.  And that information seems to be missing online.  In addition, the Tudor style architecture could be anywhere across England, France or Germany.

Comment: @PeterM the shape of the tower doesn't look typical of England.